# Comparing result from the server with a string in java 2ME

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, java-me

I'm working on a java 2ME app that submit data to mysql database (am running PHP as the scripting language), but am having problem to compare string with the result that comes from the server. I want to compare a string that has been print with PHP eg. `echo "OK";` with a string `String str = "OK"` within my java 2ME codes. Can anyone help me with this?
Here are my codes

register.java

```
public void register() {
        String result = null;
        PostHttp post = new  PostHttp();

        post.setDocument("birth");
        post.setPath("/notification/");

        //Set Parameters
        post.setParameter("firstname", getChildFirstName().getString());
        post.setParameter("middlename", getChildMiddleName().getString());
        post.setParameter("lastname", getChildLastName().getString());
        post.setParameter("gender", getChildGender().getString(getChildGender().getSelectedIndex()));/***************/
        post.setParameter("childDOB", getChildDOB().getDate().toString());/*******************/
        post.setParameter("birthType", getBirthType().getString(getBirthType().getSelectedIndex()));
        post.setParameter("weight", getBornWithWeight().getString());
        post.setParameter("mother_fname", getMotherFirstName().getString());
        post.setParameter("mother_mname", getMotherMiddleName().getString());
        post.setParameter("mother_lname", getMotherLastName().getString());
        post.setParameter("birthPlace", getPlaceOfBirth().getString());
        post.setParameter("residence", getResidence().getString());
        post.setParameter("residence", getResidence().getString());

        result = post.submit();
        String x = "OK";
        if(result.compareTo(x)){
           this.append("Equal Strings"); 
        }else{
       this.append("Not equal"); 
}
    }
```

PostHttp.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;

public class PostHttp {

    private String protocol;
    private String host;
    private String path; //path to the file
    private String document; // controller function
    private String data; // Post Data

    public PostHttp() {
        // Set the defaults
        protocol = "http://";
        host = "localhost/badis/index.php";
        path = "/notification/";
        document = "trial";
        data = "";

    }

    public void setProtocol(String p) {
        protocol = p;
    }

    public void setHost(String h) {
        host = h;
    }

    public void setPath(String p) {
        path = p;
    }

    public void setDocument(String d) {
        document = d;
    }

    public void setParameter(String parameter, String value) {

        if (data.length() > 0) {
            data = data + "&";
        }
        data = data + parameter + "=" + value;
    }

    HttpConnection setupConnection(String uri) throws IOException {
        HttpConnection connection = null;

        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(uri, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        return (connection);
    }

    void sendPostData(HttpConnection connection, String postData) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        outputStream = connection.openOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(postData.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }

    String readResult(HttpConnection connection) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader inputStream;
        String result = "";
        final int arbitraryBufferSize = 100;
        final int endOfData = -1;
        char[] characterBuffer = new char[arbitraryBufferSize];
        int bytesRead;

        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connection.openInputStream());
        bytesRead = inputStream.read(characterBuffer);
        while (bytesRead != endOfData) {
            result = result + new String(characterBuffer);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(characterBuffer);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return (result);
    }

    public String submit() {
        HttpConnection connection;
        String result;

        try {
            connection = setupConnection(protocol + host + path + document);
            sendPostData(connection, data);
            result = readResult(connection);
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            result = "IOException!";
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

Result

```
 Not equal
```

php script

```
 public function birth() {
     echo "OK";
}
```

am using codeigniter 2.0.1, if that helps.

Thanx in advance..
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets be absolutely clear about this.  If the following is appending "Not equal":

```
    String x = "OK";
    if (result.equals(x)) {
       this.append("Equal Strings"); 
    } else{
       this.append("Not equal"); 
    }
```

it is because `result` is not equal to "OK".  **There can be no doubt about this**.

I suspect that it is one of the following:

- There is leading or trailing whitespace on the `result` String; i.e. a space, TAB or CR or NL character that you can't see when you output the String to the console.
- Possibly, the first character is an zero ('0') character instead of a capital Oh ('O').
- Possibly, the case is different.

One way to get to the bottom of this is to take the two strings apart and compare them character by character; e.g.

```
String s = "OK";
if (result.equals(x)) {
    this.append("Equal Strings"); 
} else if (x.length() != result.length()) {
    this.append("Lengths are different");
} else if (x.charAt(0) != result.charAt(0)) {
    this.append("Character 0 different");
} else if (x.charAt(1) != result.charAt(1)) {
    this.append("Character 1 different");
} else {
    this.append("The universe is being swallowed by a giant squid");
}
```

Comment: thanx for pointing out it worked fine, to make it more general i made use of the trim() function.. Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

String.compareTo() returns an int. Don't you want String.equals() which returns a boolean?

Change `this.append("Not equal");` to `this.append("'" + result + "' is not equal to '" + x + "'");`

Comment: tried it but it appears the string are not equal while they are both "OK"..what might be the problem?

Comment: different in whitespace perhaps? when you print out or send the two strings to a log, with quotes around them, are they indeed identical? see updated answer.

Comment: yeah, you are right it was the whitespace that brought troubles i trim the whitesapce and now it works fine..Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

How is this even compiling? You can't convert an int to a boolean in Java.

```
if(result.compareTo(x)) {
```

Anyway, to compare strings in Java use the equals or equalsIgnoreCase method, as follows:

```
System.out.println("red".equals("red")); // Prints true
System.out.println("red".equals("RED")); // Prints false
System.out.println("red".equalsIgnoreCase("RED")); // Prints true
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the problem is it recognise as they are different, that is OK from the server is not equal to OK string in my java codes.. What might be the problem..Thnx in advance.